# Slicing a different range at each index of a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have an `m` x `n` numpy array `arr`, and for each column of `arr`, I have a given range of rows that I want to access.
I have an `n` x `1` array `vec` that describes when this range starts.
The range has some constant duration `d`.

How can I extract this `d` x `n` array of interest efficiently?
Can this be done by clever slicing?

My initial thought was to try something like:

```
arr = np.tile(np.arange(10),(4,1)).T
vec = np.array([3,4,5,4])
d = 3
vec_2 = vec+d
out = arr[vec:vec2,np.arange(n)]
```

But this gives the following error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

The desired output would be the following array:

```
array([[3, 4, 5, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 5],
       [5, 6, 7, 6],
       [6, 7, 8, 7])
```

I could loop over `d`, but performance is important for this piece of code so I would prefer to vectorize it.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use your starting indices in place of `idx` in the accepted answer from the linked Q&A. Use the transposed version of `arr` as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [489]: arr=np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)                                                         
In [490]: vec=np.array([0,2,1,3])
```

Taking advantage of the recent expansion of `linspace` to generate several arrays:

```
In [493]: x = np.linspace(vec,vec+2,3).astype(int)                                               
In [494]: x                                                                                      
Out[494]: 
array([[0, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 3, 5]])
In [495]: arr[x, np.arange(4)]                                                                   
Out[495]: 
array([[ 0,  9,  6, 15],
       [ 4, 13, 10, 19],
       [ 8, 17, 14, 23]])
```

the column iteration approach:

```
In [498]: np.stack([arr[i:j,k] for k,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(vec,vec+3))],1)                      
Out[498]: 
array([[ 0,  9,  6, 15],
       [ 4, 13, 10, 19],
       [ 8, 17, 14, 23]])
```